# comparing char with arguments from input

Tags: c, char, compare, ascii, argv

My input is: 1 + 2

I found that the value stored in `argv[2][1]` and `op` aren't the same, I just want to see if they are both the "+" operand. `op` stores the ascii value of "+" while `argv[2][1]` stores some random value. How would I compare them?

**I don't want to use "strcmp"*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array indexes start at `0`, so you need to use `[0]` to compare the first character of the argument.

```
if (argv[2][0] != c) {
```